# Issues with adding an array of moving sprites to screen?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, tags, nsmutablearray, sprite, simulator

In my program, I have created an NSMutable Array which contains a series of sprites that move across the screen (to the left)

However, while implemented in my code, they do not seem to appear on the screen simulator when tested.

Any ideas?

```
-(void) addBlocks
{

    NSMutableArray *_blocks; blocktest=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"blocksquare.png"];

    blocktest.tag = 1;

    // add the block to the array of blocks
    [_blocks addObject:blocktest];

    blocktest.position=ccp(500,100);
    id repeat2 =[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCSequence actions:
                                                   [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:7 position:ccp(-180,100)],nil]];
    [blocktest runAction:repeat2];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you haven't added blocktest to your scene ( [self addChild:blocktest] ).

Adding it to _blocks, will work as a reference to fetch your sprites later, but will not add the sprites on any layer or scene, so you won't see them anywhere

Comment: Thank you for answering all of my questions! Haha